# NSDictionary EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

```
NSInteger total = 4556; // Initialize total

// NSLog all fields to make sure the variables are in place
NSLog(@"%@", originField.text);
NSLog(@"%@", destinationField.text);
NSLog(@"%i", [startField.text integerValue]);
NSLog(@"%i", [endField.text integerValue]);
NSLog(@"%i", total);

// Create a dictionary of them
NSDictionary *newDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Sat. Jan 6th, 2014", @"date", originField.text, @"origin", destinationField.text, @"destination", [startField.text integerValue], @"start", [endField.text integerValue], @"end", total, @"total", @"Personal", @"type", nil];
// EXC_BAD_ACCESS CODE 1
```

I've tried using the Zombies template in Instruments, but I never get a dialog. When breakpointing, the app crashes on the initWithObjectsAndKeys. Where are my dead variable(s)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can not put primitive types into Dictionary. Wrap the variable total with `NSNumber` and then put it into Dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *newDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Sat. Jan 6th, 2014", @"date", 
originField.text, @"origin", 
destinationField.text, @"destination", 
@([startField.text integerValue]), @"start", 
@([endField.text integerValue]), @"end", 
@(total), @"total", 
@"Personal", @"type", nil];
```

Comment: The new notation `@(someNumber)` can be used instead, to keep that long line from getting even longer.

Comment: @HotLicks Agree. I still work with conventional style.

Comment: I kinda switch back and forth.  On a long line the concise notation is helpful, since otherwise the statement becomes unintelligible.

Answer (score -1):

You should insert the original NSSTring * Values of startField and endField into the NSDictionary and convert it to int when necessary.